# Why is this attempt at a binary search crashing?

Tags: java, crash, binary-search

I am fairly new to the concept of a binary search, and am trying to write a program that does this in Java for personal practice. I understand the concept of this well, but my code is not working.

There is a run-time exception happening in my code that just caused Eclipse, and then my computer, to crash... there are no compile-time errors here though.

---

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class BinarySearch
{
    // instance variables
    int[] arr;
    int iterations;

    // constructor
    public BinarySearch(int[] arr)
    {
        this.arr = arr;
        iterations = 0;
    }

    // instance method
    public int findTarget(int targ, int[] sorted)
    {
        int firstIndex = 1;
        int lastIndex = sorted.length;
        int middleIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
        int result = sorted[middleIndex - 1];

        while(result != targ)
        {
            if(result > targ)
            {
                firstIndex = middleIndex + 1;
                middleIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
                result = sorted[middleIndex - 1];

                iterations++;
            }
            else
            {
                lastIndex = middleIndex + 1;
                middleIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
                result = sorted[middleIndex - 1];

                iterations++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] sortedArr = new int[]
        {
            1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29
        };
        BinarySearch obj = new BinarySearch(sortedArr);

        int target = sortedArr[8];
        int result = obj.findTarget(target, sortedArr);

        System.out.println("The original target was -- " + target + ".\n" +
                            "The result found was -- " + result + ".\n" +
                            "This took " + obj.iterations + " iterations to find.");        
    } // end of main method
} // end of class BinarySearch
```

Comment: what's the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Define 'crashing' and 'a runtime exception'. This is not a guessing game.

Comment: Well, sorry to keep you guessing then. The problem is it's an infinite loop, a stackoverflow error if you will (in more ways than one?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, array indexing is zero-based. That is, the valid range of indexes is 0 up to, but *not* including, the array length. You are indexing from 1 to the array length. Try replacing this:

```
int firstIndex = 1;
int lastIndex = sorted.length;
```

with:

```
int firstIndex = 0;
int lastIndex = sorted.length - 1;
```

Also, as [@Daniel's points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12886710/535871), in the case when you update `lastIndex`, the update should be to `middleIndex - 1` (instead of to `middleIndex + 1` as you have it now).

Comment: Good spot, I didn't even see that!

Comment: @DanielFischer - Thanks. Good catch on your part, as well, regarding updating `lastIndex`. I missed that. Together we might actually solve his problem. :)

Comment: Thanks @TedHopp for the help! I wish I could choose both your and Daniel's answer as the best answers, ha. Yes, I was getting screwy with my indexing there, not sure what I was thinking (I should know better). Also, my logic is off as well -- the code block within the if-statement should be switched with that of the else. I have posted my corrected code below as an answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

```
int result = sorted[middleIndex - 1];
```

should be

```
int result = sorted[middleIndex];
```

If `lastIndex = 1`, you try to access `sorted[-1]`.

And

```
lastIndex = middleIndex + 1;
```

should be

```
lastIndex = middleIndex - 1;
```

or you may try to access past the end of `sorted`.

And, included for completeness, as [Ted Hopp spotted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12886713/1011995), you should start with

```
firstIndex = 0;
lastIndex = sorted.length-1;
```

since array indices are 0-based.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel! Your specific suggestions here were very helpful. My if-else logic was backwards as well -- switching the code block within the if statement with that of the else did the trick. With that fixed and with your suggestions, I've posted my corrected code below, as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop in your method findTarget() is running infinitely. So I am guessing that the error you get at run time should be about memory related as it keeps running for ever. 
would you consider some changes in your method findTarget()? If yes, try the sample below:

```
                 int firstIndex = 0;
                 int lastIndex = sorted.length-1;
                while (firstIndex <= lastIndex) {
                    middleIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
                    if (sorted[middleIndex] == targ) {

                            return middleIndex;
                    } else if (sorted[middleIndex] < targ) {
                         iterations++;
                        firstIndex = middleIndex + 1;
                    } else {
                         iterations++;
                           lastIndex = middleIndex - 1;
                    }
            }
            return -1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy, exactly right about the infinite loop, don't know why I didn't see that before. Your different usage of the while and if-else parameters is interesting as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not only was my index logic off (as Ted and Daniel have pointed out above), but also the code block within the if statement should be switched with that of the else.

Here is the corrected code:

```
public class BinarySearch
{
    // instance variables
    int[] arr;
    int iterations;

    // constructor
    public BinarySearch(int[] arr)
    {
        this.arr = arr;
        iterations = 0;
    }

    // instance method
    public int findTarget(int targ, int[] sorted)
    {
        int firstIndex = 0;
        int lastIndex = sorted.length - 1;
        int middleIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
        int result = sorted[middleIndex];

        iterations++;

        while(result != targ)
        {
            if(result > targ)
            {
                lastIndex = middleIndex - 1;
                middleIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
                result = sorted[middleIndex];

                iterations++;
            }
            else
            {
                firstIndex = middleIndex + 1;
                middleIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
                result = sorted[middleIndex];

                iterations++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] sortedArr = new int[]
        {
            1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29
        };
        BinarySearch obj = new BinarySearch(sortedArr);

        int target = sortedArr[8];
        int result = obj.findTarget(target, sortedArr);

        System.out.println("The original target was -- " + target + ".\n" +
                "The result found was -- " + result + ".\n" +
                "This took " + obj.iterations + " iterations to find.");        
    } // end of main method
} // end of class BinarySearch
```